# Jquery / Javascript scroll to div in page with only class element

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I'm know you can scroll to different parts of a webpage using id and name elements, but I've got some different here. I'm using a WordPress theme from Croma called Dumanis and their div only offer classes, not Id's. So I'm trying to figure a way to click on something in the navigation menu to take people to the proper div class element. How would I accomplish that? I see a lot of people refer to scrollTop but in this case, I don't want it to scroll completely to the top or the top social media bar will cover part of the div up. What to do?

Here's the page so far:
http://www.aishla.com/blog/2014/my-aish/

Comment: trivial to subtract from element's offsettop and set scrolltop accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.eq()` to grab the elements from the UL list that contains the links, then you can use `contains()` to grab the text of the H2 elements that divide the sections, here's a mockup:

```
jQuery('#sub-nav a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(window).scrollTop(jQuery('h2:contains("Contact")').offset().top - jQuery('h2:contains("Contact")').outerHeight());
});
```

Of course, this just takes every link to the `contact` portion, but you can easily abstract from this.

Plug it into the console and you'll see.

Comment: You're right. Worked great! Now I just have to figure out to scrollTop -100 or so pixels. Refresh the example, and you'll see the problem.